# Multiple object properties assignment in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, properties, three.js

Is there some kind of shorthand for this?

```
object.position.x = position.x
object.position.y = position.y
object.position.z = position.z

object.rotation.x = rotation.x
object.rotation.y = rotation.y
object.rotation.z = rotation.z
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With ES6 Spread Operator you can do it easier in one line, for the question sample:

```
object = {...object, position, rotation}
```

Just notice it will replace new properties with old one

Comment: Shouldn't it replace old properties with new one?

Comment: Should be, just notice if you add some properties ( for example add object.rotation.a ) to old property that not exists in new one they will lose.

Comment: Thanks. But then it would be possible to spread nested objects also, if needed.

Comment: sure, `rotation = { ...object.rotation, ...rotation }` , merge old `object.rotation` and new `rotation` before pass to object, by the way we have all `object.rotation` properties with replaced `rotation` values

Answer (score 12):

Yes you can use `Object.assign()`.

```js
var obj = {}
var position = {x: 1, y: 2, z: 3}
var rotation = {x: 1, y: 2, z: 3}

obj.position = Object.assign({}, position);
obj.rotation = Object.assign({}, rotation);

console.log(obj)
```

If you only want to take specific properties from object you can create your pick function using `map()` to get array of objects and later use spread syntax to assign each object.

```js
var obj = {}
var position = {x: 1, y: 2, z: 3}
var rotation = {x: 1, y: 2, z: 3}

function pick(obj, props) {
  return props.map(e => ({[e]: obj[e]}))
}

obj.position = Object.assign({}, ...pick(position, ['x', 'y']));
obj.rotation = Object.assign({}, ...pick(rotation, ['x', 'y', 'z']));

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use a direct approach by assigning the objects directly,

```
object.position = position;
object.rotation = rotation;
```

or with an array and the keys with iterating the properties.

```
['x', 'y', 'z'].forEach(function (k) {
    object.position[k] = position[k];
    object.rotation[k] = rotation[k];
});
```

Answer (score 8):

My advice: **DON'T USE ANY "CLEVER" LOOPS AND DYNAMIC SH*T**

Reasons:

1. It's just a few lines, not a ton of lines, don't do overengineering
2. It's so much readable, that even IDE can help you with autosuggestions

Comment: i agree all solutions look more work than simply using ide shortcuts like multiple cursors

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a for...in loop, it's simple and quite readable. Example:

```
for ( const property in position ) {
    object.position[property] = position[property];
}
```

MDN reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in